# Vitest testing components of a Nuxt.Js project (using primevue component library)

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vitest, primevue

I am making a web application using Nuxt.js. I am fairly new to this framework. The component I have finished working on is a wizard component. This wizard is a modal that takes in an array of form components with labels. This array is passed to the wizard as props, rendering the steps for the wizard accordingly.

This is how I pass the wizard steps to the wizard modal component itself.

```
<template>

 
    <WizardModal
        :wizard-title="wizardTitle"
        :wizard-status="wizardStatus"
        :wizard-steps="wizardSteps"
        @close-wizard="handleCloseWizard()"
    />

</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, shallowRef } from "vue";
import PersonInformationForm from "~/components/wizard/wizardForms/personalInformationForm.vue";
import PaymentInformationForm from "~/components/wizard/wizardForms/paymentInformationForm.vue";
import ConfigurationForm from "~/components/wizard/wizardForms/configurationForm.vue";
import TestForm from "~/components/wizard/wizardForms/testForm.vue";

const isWizardOpen = ref(false);
const wizardTitle = ref("wash product");
const wizardStatus = ref("new");
const wizardSteps = shallowRef([
  {
    label: "Details",
    component: PersonInformationForm,
  },
  {
    label: "Config",
    component: ConfigurationForm,
  },
  {
    label: "Payment",
    component: PaymentInformationForm,
  },
  {
    label: "Test",
    component: TestForm,
  },
]);

const openWizard = () => {
  isWizardOpen.value = true;
};

const handleCloseWizard = () => {
  isWizardOpen.value = false;
};
</script>
```

This is the wizardModal that uses various primevue components to complete the full functionality of a wizard.

```
<template>
  <div class="modal-container">
    <div v-show="!isMobile" ref="closeWizardRef" class="wizard-container">
      <!-- Top information ribbon -->
      <div class="wizard-progress grid grid-nogutter">
        <Toast />

        <div class="wizard-header col-2">
          <h4 class="mb-1 text-gray-500 font-normal text-base m-0">
            {{ status }}
          </h4>
          <h3
            :class="
              isTablet ? 'm-0 font-normal text-xl' : 'm-0 font-normal text-2xl'
            "
          >
            {{ title }}
          </h3>
        </div>

        <div class="progress-container col-8">
          <Steps
            :active-step="activeStep"
            :model="steps"
            class="pointer-events-none"
            :readonly="false"
          >
            <template #item="{ item, active }">
              <div
                class="z-1 text-center pt-2 cursor-pointer pointer-events-auto"
                @click.stop.prevent="changeToAnyStep(item)"
              >
                <span class="custom-svg-container">
                  <svg
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    width="32"
                    height="32"
                    viewBox="0 0 32 32"
                    fill="none"
                  >
                    <!-- if current step -->
                    <path
                      v-if="active"
                      d="M4.85749 16.5145L5.16619 16L4.85749 15.4855L1 9.05635L1 1L31 1L31 31L1 31L1 22.9437L4.85749 16.5145Z"
                      fill="#DD4814"
                      stroke="#DD4814"
                      stroke-width="2"
                    />
                    <!-- if step has been passed -->
                    <path
                      v-else-if="activeStep > findIndexByLabel(item.label)"
                      d="M4.85749 16.5145L5.16619 16L4.85749 15.4855L1 9.05635L1 1L31 1L31 31L1 31L1 22.9437L4.85749 16.5145Z"
                      fill="#F8DBD0"
                      stroke="#DD4814"
                      stroke-width="2"
                    />
                    <!-- if step has not been reached -->
                    <path
                      v-else
                      d="M4.85749 16.5145L5.16619 16L4.85749 15.4855L1 9.05635L1 1L31 1L31 31L1 31L1 22.9437L4.85749 16.5145Z"
                      fill="#F8DBD0"
                      stroke="#888888"
                      stroke-width="2"
                    />
                  </svg>
                </span>

                <p
                  class="m-0"
                  :style="
                    activeStep >= findIndexByLabel(item.label)
                      ? ''
                      : 'opacity: 50%'
                  "
                >
                  {{ item.label }}
                </p>
              </div>
            </template>
          </Steps>
        </div>

        <div v-show="isDesktop" class="col-2 text-right pr-3">
          <Button
            label="Cancel"
            primary
            outlined
            style="font-size: 16px; font-style: normal; font-weight: 400"
            @click="closeWizardModal()"
          />
        </div>
        <div v-show="isTablet" class="col-2 text-center">
          <i
            class="pi pi-times-circle"
            style="color: #dd4814; font-size: 1.7rem; cursor: pointer"
            @click="closeWizardModal()"
          ></i>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!--Wizard Forms-->
      <div class="wizard-form px-3 pb-3 h-full">
        <div data-multi-step class="multi-step-form h-full w-full p-1">
          <div
            v-for="(formComponent, index) in steps"
            :key="index"
            class="card-container"
            :class="{ active: index === activeStep }"
            data-step
          >
            <!-- Set the current form component as a references in the wizard -->
            <component :is="formComponent.component" ref="form" />

            <div class="button-container">
              <span v-show="index == 0"></span>
              <wizard-nav-btns
                :previous-label="getPrevFormLabel(index)"
                :next-label="getNextFormLabel(index)"
                :finish-label="'Complete'"
                :index="index"
                :steps-length="steps.length"
                @prev="prevStep()"
                @next="nextStep(index, 'desktop/tablet')"
                @finish="complete(index, 'desktop/tablet')"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I am now writing tests for this component using Vitest and vue/test-utils. However, I am facing difficulties. I have written other tests for different components in my application but am having issues with components that use primevue components specifically. I am struggling to find much documentation or solutions online for the warnings/errors I am facing, hence my plea for help!

This is what I have so far for the test, I can not render the component at all even with all the required props. I just want to test if the component renders at all. Then I can start diving deeper into the testing.

```
import { mount } from "@vue/test-utils";
import { expect, vi } from "vitest";
import WizardModal from "~/components/wizard/wizardModal.vue";
import TestForm from "~/components/wizard/wizardForms/testForm.vue";
import Toast from "primevue/toast";
import Steps from "primevue/steps";
import Button from "primevue/button";
import Knob from "primevue/knob";
import Menu from "primevue/menu";
import PrimeVue from "primevue/config";
import ToastService from "primevue/toastservice";

describe("WizardModalComponent Tests", () => {
  const wizardTitle = "Test Wizard";
  const wizardStatus = "In Progress";
  const wizardSteps = [
    { label: "Step 1", component: TestForm },
    { label: "Step 2", component: TestForm },
    { label: "Step 3", component: TestForm },
  ];

  it("Renders WizardModalComponent with default props", () => {
    const wrapper = mount(WizardModal, {
      global: {
        plugins: [PrimeVue, ToastService],
        components: {
          Toast,
          Steps,
          Button,
          Knob,
          Menu,
        },
      },
      props: {
        wizardTitle,
        wizardStatus,
        wizardSteps,
      },

    });
    console.log("props: ", wrapper.props());
    console.log("HTML rendered: ", wrapper.html());
  });

});
```

I am getting this warning:
`[Vue warn]: injection "Symbol()" not found.`

and this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'tabIndex')
 ❯ Proxy.mounted node_modules/primevue/steps/steps.cjs.js:57:24
     55|   mounted: function mounted() {
     56|     var firstItem = this.findFirstItem();
     57|     firstItem.tabIndex = '0';
       |                        ^
     58|   },
     59|   methods: {
```

any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: plugins: [PrimeVue] should be enough for it to work correctly. Try to debug where `njection "Symbol()" not found` occurs, it can be relevant. I'd expect it to work with vitest/jest's fake dom